# Ocaml error message Error: Parse error: “in” expected after [binding] (in [expr])

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to write a function that determines whether the according password of an user is equal to the given password.

I get the error Error: Parse error: "in" expected after [binding] (in [expr]) for the last line of code, but I don't really see how "in" could be the last line. What am I doing incorrectly here?

```
let check_pwd user pwd =
  try List.assoc user userlist = pwd with Not_found -> false
```

Comment: The error is not in the code you show here. Possibly elsewhere you're using a `let` without a matching `in`, a pretty common error I think.

Comment: you need to post out more codes

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, there must be a `let` without its `in` in the code before these lines.

The best way to avoid syntax error messages located far away from the actual error: use the `;;` at the end of each phrase.